# Running Python File from Command Line with Libraries in venv

Tags: python, command-line, pycharm, python-venv

I'm using Python 3.6 in Windows and using PyCharm. I have a .py file that is using packages installed on a venv which is in a different folder to the .py file.

I'm trying to run this .py from command line and when I do it gives me a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '<module>'`. The file works fine from PyCharm just not from the command line because the packages are in the venv.

How can I get the file to run without errors from command line and keep the packages in the venv?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to activate the virtual environment by callling the activation script:

```
<path to your environment>\Scripts\activate.bat
```

as indicated [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html). Then you will automatically use all the packages installed in this environment when calling your script. Your pycharm is probably set up to automatically use your virtual evnironment

Comment: @blountdj, did you manage to set it up using a .bat file. I don't think pycharm produces it for its environments. How do I get it?

Comment: @Kvothe it is in `<your project directory>\venv\Scripts\activate.bat`. That is the default location where pycharm creates a venv

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my environment directory does not contain `Scripts`. It contains directories called `bin`, `include`, `lib`, `lib64` (link only) and `share`. `bin` does contain something called `activate` but it has no '.bat' extension.

Comment: What is your OS? And which virtualenv tool are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04, created the environment using Pycharm.

Comment: A `.bat` file is a DOS script that can be run using `cmd` on windows. Of course it will not be there on ubuntu. `source bin/activate` will activate your environment

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I Think the easiest way to do that is using shebang, and it works both linux and  windows.
For windows you just have to add `#!.\venv\Scripts\python.exe` at the very first line at your .py script file.

Answer (score 0):

Or
`source <path to your environment>/bin/activate`
on linux